What are the consequences change type of columns of table under view?
Lets say we have table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MA]
(
[A] [int] NOT NULL (PK),
[B] decimal(5,0) NULL,
[C] decimal(15,0) NULL,
[D] [nvarchar] (18)  null
)

And view
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VI_MA]
As
Select 
A,
B,
C,
D 
from [dbo].[MA]

Lets say we are changing type in table MA for B to int and C to bigint. What are the consequences for View and applications which are using this view ? They will still see decimals or int and bigint (automatic parse ?)?


Lets say we are changing type in table MA for B to int and C to bigint. What are the consequences for View and applications which are using this view ?

It depends.

They will still see decimals or int and bigint (automatic parse ?)?

Some consuming applications look at the metadata of the view and base their interpretations off of that. When you alter the schema of the underlying tables that a view references, this does not automatically refresh that metadata for the view, and the old (incorrect) data types will still be stored in the metadata. The view needs to be recompiled which can be done via an ALTER script or by executing the system procedure sp_refreshview:

Updates the metadata for the specified non-schema-bound view. Persistent metadata for a view can become outdated because of changes to the underlying objects upon which the view depends.

Other consuming applications try to be smart and will analyze the data (sometimes proactively, other times at runtime) to determine what the returned data types are. One example of this is EF Core who will throw errors at runtime if the data returned from the database doesn't compatibly match the defined data type of its model in C#, regardless if the view's metadata matches the model definition.
To prevent changes to the underlying table that otherwise would've conflicted with the schema of the view, you can use the SCHEMABINDING keyword in your view's definition:

Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified.


Changing data type of a column is a critical issue. You need to refresh schema of all dependent objects not just views by using ALTER statement.
You can find dependent object list by using sp_depends
sp_depends [TableName]

Its result is as follows

You can also use SSMS object explorer > right click> View Dependencies


In addition to refreshing schema of dependent objects you need to consider to test their behaviour.
They are functioning correctly or malfunctioning.

